# Can i use Sqlite query for edit SMS's database

Tags: android, sqlite, sms

Can i use Sqlite query for edit SMS's database?
I used contentResolver for edit SMS but it doesn't work properly!! 
I searched for this problem but i couldn't find useful answer! many developers have same problem!

Thanks.

---

I wonder if you could get me some help.
I want change SMS's number in inbox and sent box in android.
I have problem with Delete, Insert and Update commands in getContentResolver. They don't work!!!
 I searched for this problem but i couldn't find useful answer! 
I read many questions and answers for  this problem but None of them can't solve my problem!!
This code changes SMS's number and works in SDK 17. but doesn't work in SDK 20 !!! Update command never worked in any SDK's version!! For this reason i read required information then delete SMS and insert new SMS with old information and new phone number.

```
 String[] prj={"_id","body","address","date","seen","read","type","thread_id","date_sent","status"};
    Cursor cr=SMS_Service.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, prj, null, null, null);

   while(cr.moveToNext())
    {

        String _body=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("body"));
        String _date=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("date"));
        String _seen=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("seen"));
        String _read=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("read"));
        String _type=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("type"));
        String MsgID=cr.getString(0);
        String _date_sent=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("date_sent"));
        String _status=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("status"));

        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put("body", _body);
        values.put("address", "0123456789");//New phone's number
        values.put("date", _date);
        values.put("seen", _seen);
        values.put("read", _read);
        values.put("type", _type);
        values.put("date_sent", _date_sent);
        values.put("status", _status);

      String where="_id=?";
         String[] filter={cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(Sms._ID))};

            SMS_Service.this.getContentResolver().delete(Sms.CONTENT_URI,where, filter);
         SMS_Service.this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

        }
```

I use These premissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Can i use Sqlite query for edit SMS's database (mmssms.db) ?

Comment: It depends on a few things. You need to be more specific about your situation, and show what you've tried.

Comment: what do you expect `SMS_Service.this.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null);` to do exactly ?

Comment: Hi. I correct that line. Please see this again

Answer (score 2):

if you want to modify SMS database in devices which have API > 18 you have to make your app become default app in your device. I followed this link and successed (you need to read carefully and follow all what they say, especially example about mandifest, you need to write all permissions, intent filters even your app doesn't have any function like sending or receiving message...)
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: It's actually API > 18.

Comment: sorry, i think it's API > 19

Comment: No, it's API >= 19, or API > 18; same thing. It started with KitKat.